# Books/resources on non-existence

Tags: existence, death

I believe that after we die there is nothing. The same that was before being born. So while I won’t care about not existing when it happens, the thought of it does bother me now, as I like *being* and would like for that to continue.

When I close my eyes I see darkness, black. But according to various sources, blind people see nothing. I’m not capable of imagining what seeing nothing really means, but I have wondered often that it may get one a step closer to being able to understand what it is to *be* nothing (or, more accurately, to not be). To clarify, I’m not claiming to believe blind people have a deeper understanding of non-existence, just that they have an extra data point, an experience that I don’t that may allow new insights on how to rationalise the process.

I am interested in this notion of non-existence, and would like some recommendations on it. On first look I thought ontology would be the branch of philosophy to read on (I’m not completely convinced it isn’t), but I’ve read part of [Sartre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Paul_Sartre)’s [Being and Nothingness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_and_Nothingness) and what he discusses isn’t exactly what I’m looking for. I also found the writing somewhat boring.

I’ve also started to look into [Yale’s course on Death](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2J7wSuFRl8&list=PLEA18FAF1AD9047B0) and found the first few videos interesting (I’m less than a fifth in) and don’t know yet if it’s what I’m looking for, but it’s interesting enough for me to keep watching.

What’s the branch of philosophy that concerns itself with non-existence, especially after death? What good literature is there on it? The more logical the arguments, the better. Please **be specific in your recommendations**. I’m looking for “read this book by this person”, not “read the entire history of this religion, as sometimes they mention it”.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but just a comment about what seeing darkness might be like. While on a tour with many others in a cave the guide told us that he was going to turn off the lights to show us total darkness.  When he did so it felt as if space had collapsed onto my face. This might be even darker than what blind people experience, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: "Death is only the end if you think the story is about you" You are not a Cartesian 'cogitoer', you came from a context, and a context will remain after you, a little changed. It is baffling vanity to not see or value that.

Comment: @FrankHubeny “This might be even darker than what blind people experience”. To clarify, in the reports I’ve seen where it’s mentioned blind people don’t see anything, not black, not darkness, just nothing, some of these are from formerly sighted people, so they’d know the difference.

Comment: @CriglCragl I don’t see your point. I don’t think “the story” is about anyone. I think we all don’t matter equally. What difference is it to me that there are  contexts before and after me? My existence consists of my experiences. When I’m no longer around to experience anything, by definition I won’t care about past of future events.

Comment: "to being able to understand what it is to be nothing (or, more accurately, to not be)." Isn't it the case that there is nothing it is like to be nothing? Zero experiences. By definition, you can't experience a lack of experience. Or to put it a funny way: Remember before you were born, how that was? Being dead will feel like that.

Comment: @Chelonian “Isn't it the case that there is nothing it is like to be nothing? Zero experiences. By definition, you can't experience a lack of experience”. Correct. However, there’re also zero experiences about what it’s like to have a black hole in your pocket and we can’t experience that, but [it doesn’t stop us from hypothesizing](https://youtu.be/8nHBGFKLHZQ), and it also doesn’t stop said hypothesizing from being interesting.

Comment: @user137369 As long as you accept that there is nothing it is like to not exist, I'm fine with it. Further elaboration should be taken to a chatroom here.

Comment: No such resources exist.

Comment: I wouldn't say "blind people have an extra data point about nonexistence," as every human is constantly *not receiving* an infinite amount of information about the world. A totally blind person doesn't just *not experience* seeing, they can't *comprehend* it any more than we are able to comprehend seeing ultraviolet light like bees do. Unless, of course, the blind person was previously able to see, and can't anymore.

Comment: @Challenger5 “I wouldn't say "blind people have an extra data point about nonexistence,"”. Neither did I. I specifically said I wasn’t saying that. What I said is they have an experience that I don’t. I have no idea if said experience is relevant or not, but I’d like to know.

Comment: @Challenger5 “A totally blind person doesn't just not experience seeing, they can't comprehend”. I don’t get why you used this example if you could refute it right after: “Unless, of course, the blind person was previously able to see”.

Comment: @Challenger5 “any more than we are able to comprehend seeing ultraviolet light like bees do”. But we *are* able to comprehend it. We can see it with instruments and measure it, [Neil Harbinson can feel it](https://livestream.com/accounts/6779986/events/2928486/videos/51486919), and [Claude Monet could see it](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2131608/Claude-Monet-How-famed-artist-ultraviolet-just-like-animals.html).

Comment: @user137369 1. Perhaps I misinterpreted your comment: "I’m not claiming to believe blind people have a deeper understanding of non-existence, just that they have an extra data point." 2. There are people who are blind from birth and people who were able to see but then became blind. My comment specifically refers to the former group, because the latter group would have some experience to compare to.

Comment: 3. Such instruments render information that most humans can't detect and turn it into information our senses can pick (i.e. visible light), the same way a deaf person can use a spectrometer (and with enough training, could probably learn to pick out voices and usable sounds). Perhaps ultraviolet light was a bad example - my point was that brains learn to interpret the electrical impulses coming from nerves throughout the body. We have no way to access or comprehend *any* information unless it arrives, in some form, through these impulses.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, an easy question for a change. The entire literature of the Perennial philosophy, mysticism, nondualism, call it what you will, is devoted to explaining that you do not exist, or at least not in the way you usually imagine. This is said to be what we discover if we take the advice to 'Know Thyself'.

Middle Way Buddhism, for instance, is philosophically grounded on Nagarjuna's logical proof that nothing really exists and nothing ever really happens. You might like to check out the doctrine of 'dependent existence' and the theory of emptiness. Radhkrishnan's 'Philosophy of the Upanishads' might be a useful starting point, or Gyamptso's book on Nagarjuna 'The Sun of Wisdom' (Shambala)

And then of course, there's the cantor, the rabbi and the janitor.

The cantor (he's the guy who sings in Jewish services) was getting ready to leave and was suddenly overwhelmed with a sense of devotion. He went up to the front of the temple, got down on his knees and called out,"Oh Lord, Lord, I am the least of your children. Truly I am nothing."

The rabbi happened to see this, and went up to the front, sat down next to the cantor, and cried out, "Oh Lord, I too am the lowest of the low. Oh truly, truly, I am nothing."

Well, the janitor happened to overhear this as he was sweeping, and went down and sat down on the other side of the cantor, and poured out his devotion, "Lord, Lord, Lord, I am less than the dust at your feet. Truly, I am nothing."

At which point the rabbi jabbed the cantor in the ribs and said, "Hah!  Look who thinks HE'S nothing!"

Comment: I believe I exist in some form and will cease to. Asking me to chuck all that away and concentrate on the entirely different premisse that I don’t exist right now doesn’t really answer the question.

Comment: @user137369 - You asked who studied this issue and where to find relevant literature and I told you. I;m afraid I can no better.

Comment: “You asked who studied this issue and where to find relevant literature and I told you”. Thank you for the recommendation, but I disagree the literature was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of fear of death is that it's an irrational fear:

> If I am, then death is not.If Death is, then I am not.Why should I
>   fear that which can only exist when I do not. (*Epicurus*)

If fear of death is irrational, then why do we fear death? Because we are not completely intelligent creatures, but we have an irrational organismic side, a result of which is that we are controlled by instincts, specifically here the instinct of self-preservation, which is:

> Natural or instinctive tendency to act so as to preserve
>   one's own existence.

This is only why we fear death.

---

> Kierkegaard was the first to make a clear distinction between **fear** and
>   **anxiety** (dread); he contrasted fear that is fear of some thing with
>   dread that is a fear of no thing-"not," as he wryly noted, "a nothing
>   with which the individual has nothing to do." (*Existential psychotherapy*)

The way we deal with anxiety is by transforming it into a fear, as fear can be defined and dealt with:

> The nothing which is the object of dread becomes, as it were, more and
>   more a something.(*Kierkegaard, Concept of Dread, P. 55*)

The nothing here is death and the something could be anything (Ex: social anxiety). Death is nothing, because as I mentioned before, it's irrational due to being an instinct.

This leads to the fact that fear of death rarely comes in its non diluted literal form, it usually comes in the form of a seemingly unrelated manifestation.

What the genius Kierkegaard is point to, is a defense mechanism which leads to the repression of death anxiety.

This is what Ernest Becker says on the repression of death anxiety:

> If this fear were as constantly conscious, we should be unable to
>   function normally. It must be properly repressed to keep us living
>   with any modicum of comfort. We know very well that to repress means
>   more than to put away and to forget that which was put away and the
>   place where we put it. It means also to maintain a constant
>   psychological effort to keep the lid on and inwardly never relax our
>   watchfulness. (*The denial of death, p.17*)

What we conclude, is that who repress pay the price of their repression (Endless death anxiety manifestations) and who does not repress (as in your case) will pay the price of not repressing (Death anxiety).

Every conscious existence will have to pay for their existence, unless you are not a maniac free of the body and its guilt, you will pay.

Comment: You seem to already be making the concluding argument that fear of death is irrational. But I’m not looking for such a conclusion. I *know* fear of death is irrational. I don’t want conclusions handed, I want literature on the process that will make me arrive to my conclusions in a way that I’m ultimately satisfied with.

Comment: What i wanted to conclude that, it's a dead end: Either deny death or fear it, there is no coming with terms with death.

Comment: All due respect, I didn’t ask for conclusions, I asked for literature. I already agree with your conclusion, what I want are more in-depth arguments to study.

Comment: @user137369 - Okay. My bad. I wonder why you asked about the branch of philosophy that concerns itself with non-existence, especially after death. I know of only one.